# VSCode 1.62 - Definition for rule 'testing-library/no-debug' was not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

Got this error message `Definition for rule 'testing-library/no-debug' was not found.` right after VSCode update. Tried to install @types/testing-library, it didn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find `testing-library/no-debug` in your Eslint config then change it to `testing-library/no-debugging-utils`.

Ref:
https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/migration-guides/v5.md#steps-to-upgrade

Comment: eslint-plugin-testing-library author here! @warizz is right! This rule was renamed in v5 and flagged as a breaking change, so you need to rename it in your ESLint config.

Comment: Hi, does node version 14.17.3 works? I'm getting the same error in my eslintrc.json even after renaming